# How to use theme messages in form validation errors in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I use errors.rejectValue when error is found in validation.

Using this method, I just need to specify the involve field name and the error code, then Spring will help me find the code in the default messages.properties.
But I want to use the error message under some themes, like in messages-theme1.properties.

With the same error message code, how to use the messages in theme message files as error, instead of the default messages file?

Comment: Instead of the `Locale` use the `Theme`? Why? To make that work you would have to implement your own `MessageSource` which takes that into account instead of the `Locale`.

Comment: Coz it's not locale-specific, i just need to change the same error message under some business criteria. I have implemented a class that extends ResourceBundleThemeSource and have this bean in applicationContext, and I can use the theme messages in jsp using <spring:theme> tag, but i have no clue how to use theme messages in validation errors.